# View.setVisibility not works after use Animation fade_in/out

Tags: android, animation, view, visibility

Why does mImageView.setVisibility not works after I use one animation?

I have this code works fine (CODE1)...

```
    tbnVisible.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```

Any time I click at the ToggleButton (tbnVisible) and my CODE1 run perfectly and my ImageVies appears and hide. After that, I run the CODE2 to run one Animation with fade in the same View (mImageView).

THIS IS THE CODE2...

```
    btnAlphaAPI.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlphaAnimation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
            AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);

            mAlphaAnimation = mFadeOut ? fadeIn : fadeOut;
            mAlphaAnimation.setDuration(2000);
            mAlphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            mImageView.startAnimation(mAlphaAnimation);

            mAlphaAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mFadeOut =  !mFadeOut;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This code run perfectly too... until know, that's ok, the problem is when I try to run de CODE1 again. When I click in the ToggleButton (tbnVisible) not happens more with my mImageView. Just the CODE1 not works more after run the CODE2.

Somebody know what's happens?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Why doesn't setVisibility work after a view is animated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690029/why-doesnt-setvisibility-work-after-a-view-is-animated), have you tried using `clearAnimation` on the View?