# How are methods View.clearAnimation and Animation.AnimationListener.onAnimationEnd related?

Tags: android, animation, visibility

I was having a problem, where `setVisibility()` would not work properly after applying an animation to a view once.

**PROBLEM**
*public void show():*
 1. setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) is called on a view
 2. View appearance is animated:
    view.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(3000). *etc...*

*public void hide()*
 1. View disappearance is animated:
    view.animate().alpha(0.0f).setDuration(3000). *etc...*
 2. View visibility is set to GONE

- Very first show() method call displays everything correctly.
- After calling hide() afterwards, views are hidden correctly.
- **Calling show() now, animates the view appearance up to the very ending of the animation, immediately after which the view disappears (Layout inspector indicates its final visibility is GONE)**

This is my initial animation code:

```
myGridView.animate()
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setDuration(100);
```

Surprisingly, adding `AnimatorListenerAdapter` and overriding `onAnimationEnd` without doing anything else solved the problem.
Recently, I have found other [SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690029/why-doesnt-setvisibility-work-after-a-view-is-animated), where they call `clearAnimation()` on the view before `setVisibility()`.

So, this in the code worked:

```
myGridView.clearAnimation();
myGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My final code I sticked with:

```
myGridView.animate()
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(100);
        .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                myGridView.clearAnimation();
                myGridView.setVisibility(GridView.GONE);
            }
        });
```

**QUESTION**
*Why overriding `onAnimationEnd` worked on its own? Is it somehow related to `clearAnimation` ?*

Comment: I couldn't get what didn't happen previously that now happens.

Comment: @azizbekian Fair point. I have edited the question now.
The view used to disappear right after animation finishes, although before starting the animation I set its visibility to VISIBLE. After overriding onAnimationEnd method it just remains VISIBLE not only when animation starts, but also after it finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

> Why overriding *onAnimationEnd* worked on its own? Is it somehow related to *clearAnimation*?

`clearAnimation()` would initiate `onAnimationCancel()` followed by `onAnimationEnd()` to be called on the `Animation` that this view has.